# preventing autosys job to run on certain timing of the certain day

Tags: autosys

I have a job which runs everyday 4 times in an hour (total 48 times).
I want to prevent it from running only between 7 AM to 9 AM Sunday. How can I achieve it without creating two different jobs. I want to accomplish it in a single job. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Mention all the time the job `should` run in `start_times` like below

*replace .. with missing times

```
start_times: "00:00, 00:15, .... 06:30, 06:45, 9:15, 9:30, .. 23:45"
```

Comment: It would not serve my purpose, I only want to prevent on Sunday for specific time.
If I put a start times, it will be applied to week days also.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to create a calender defined as Every Sunday 07:00 till 09:00.

And then in the Job defination assign this calender to job attribute exclude_calendar along with your run_calendar.

Comment: Thank you Piyush,
Could you please help in defining Extended calendar parameters need to set to run that extended calendar only on 6AM to 9AM Sunday.
 Do I need to define this period in "cycle name" parameter of extended calendar.

I will map this extender calendar in EXCLUDE_CALENDAR clause.

Comment: i tried searching to make such a calander but i couldnot find any way to do what i had thought ealier.

The only way i feel is to create seperate jobs.
Good luck.
@MandarBailur

Comment: [Here](https://techdocs.broadcom.com/us/en/ca-enterprise-software/intelligent-automation/autosys-workload-automation/12-0-01/reference/ae-job-information-language/jil-job-definitions/exclude-calendar-attribute-define-days-to-exclude-a-job-from-running.html) you can find more details regarding the `exclude_calendar` attribute