# Do not run an Autosys job on a specific day

Tags: python, autosys

Hope you are doing well!

Actually my query is - I want an Autosys job to not run on 1st Jan of Every Year. I think it would be done by Exclude_calendar.
Could you please help how can we write script in python for that?

Please help me .I am newbie about Autosys jobs nd Python as well.
I need your help. Could you please help me?

Thank you in Advance!!

Comment: Autosys uses JIL syntax and not python language.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Piyush.Can you please let me know What would be the JIL syntax for that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51833555/preventing-autosys-job-to-run-on-certain-timing-of-the-certain-day)

Answer (score 0):

Its always better to include what all you have tried and tested out.

**Step1**: create a CYCLE and then Extended Calendar

```
cycle: YEARLY_JAN
start_date: 01/01/1972
end_date: 01/05/1972
```

***1972** indicates for all future years*

```
extended_calendar: FIRST_DAY_JAN
workday: 
non_workday:
holiday: S
holcal:
cyccal: YEARLY_JAN
adjust:
condition: MNTHD#1
```

***MNTHD#1** indicates first date of the month*

**Step2**: Use the calendar in **exclude_calendar** attribute for the required job

```
update_job: BATCH_JOB_TO_UPDATE
exclude_calendar: FIRST_DAY_JAN
```

Welcome.

Comment: Thanks a lot Piyush!! Yeah Sure, next time I will include all whatever I would have done/tested. Thanks:)

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer by clicking ✓ on the left and upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you.

Comment: [Here](https://techdocs.broadcom.com/us/en/ca-enterprise-software/intelligent-automation/autosys-workload-automation/12-0-01/reference/ae-job-information-language/jil-job-definitions/exclude-calendar-attribute-define-days-to-exclude-a-job-from-running.html) you can find more details regarding the `exclude_calendar` attribute